# laravel using eloquent to populate select box and blade

Tags: php, laravel, select

I want to populate a select box with `users` from my database i need to get the id and name of the user.

I want to create a select box like the one below:

```
<select>
  <option value="$user->id">$user->name</option>
  <option value="$user->id">$user->name</option>
</select>
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

controller

```
$users = User::all()->orderBy('name', 'asc')->lists('name','id');
```

view

```
{{ Form::select('user', $users , Input::old('users')) }}
```

Comment: Get rid of the call to `all()`. It is returning a Collection, and then you're calling `orderBy()` and `lists()` on the Collection object. It will work, but is not as efficient.

Comment: `Users::orderBy('name', 'asc')->pluck('name', 'id')` in Laravel 5.2+

Answer (score 2):

**Controller:**

```
View::share('users', User::all());
```

**View:**

```
<select name="user_id">
    @foreach($users as $user)
        <option value="{{$user->id}}">{{$user->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Use one of `all()` or `get()`, don't use both.